# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: “image_path” :image_preloader of “tflearn” package

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tflearn, image-preloader

I'm trying to classify images of Cats & Dogs using following [link](https://github.com/Vikramank/Deep-Learning-/blob/master/Cats-and-Dogs/Cats%20and%20Dogs%20Image%20Classification.ipynb).

In ANACONDA NAVIGATOR, i've faced problem to install package "**tflearn**" under **Environment** part. There have no any **tflearn** package. After suffering some problem through ANACONDA PROMPT, **tflearn** successfully installed in **Anaconda3** folder. But then by running following code:

1st cell:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn
from PIL import Image
%matplotlib inline
#for writing text files
import glob
import os     
import random 
#reading images from a text file
from tflearn.data_utils import image_preloader
import math
```

following WARNING has occured:

> **curses is not supported on this machine (please install/reinstall**
>   **curses for an optimal experience**

However after running following 3 cells i've not get any kind of error:

2nd cell (just for importing required image folder & creating data set as .txt format):

```
IMAGE_FOLDER = '/Users/sarfaraz/Anaconda3/Dataset_for_Cats_Dogs/train'
TRAIN_DATA = '/Users/sarfaraz/Anaconda3/Dataset_for_Cats_Dogs/training_data.txt'
TEST_DATA = '/Users/sarfaraz/Anaconda3/Dataset_for_Cats_Dogs/test_data.txt'
VALIDATION_DATA = '/Users/sarfaraz/Anaconda3/Dataset_for_Cats_Dogs/validation_data.txt'
train_proportion=0.7
test_proportion=0.2 
validation_proportion=0.1
```

3rd cell:

```
#read the image directories
filenames_image = os.listdir(IMAGE_FOLDER)
#shuffling the data is important otherwise the model will be fed with a single class data for a long time and 
#network will not learn properly
random.shuffle(filenames_image)
```

4th cell:

```
#total number of images
total=len(filenames_image)
##  *****training data******** 
fr = open(TRAIN_DATA, 'w')
train_files=filenames_image[0: int(train_proportion*total)]
for filename in train_files:
    if filename[0:3] == 'cat':
        fr.write(IMAGE_FOLDER + '/'+ filename + ' 0\n')
    elif filename[0:3] == 'dog':
        fr.write(IMAGE_FOLDER + '/'+ filename + ' 1\n')

fr.close()
##  *****testing data******** 
fr = open(TEST_DATA, 'w')
test_files=filenames_image[int(math.ceil(train_proportion*total)):int(math.ceil((train_proportion+test_proportion)*total))]
for filename in test_files:
    if filename[0:3] == 'cat':
        fr.write(IMAGE_FOLDER + '/'+ filename + ' 0\n')
    elif filename[0:3] == 'dog':
        fr.write(IMAGE_FOLDER + '/'+ filename + ' 1\n')
fr.close()

##  *****validation data******** 
fr = open(VALIDATION_DATA, 'w')
valid_files=filenames_image[int(math.ceil((train_proportion+test_proportion)*total)):total]
for filename in valid_files:
    if filename[0:3] == 'cat':
        fr.write(IMAGE_FOLDER + '/'+ filename + ' 0\n')
    elif filename[0:3] == 'dog':
        fr.write(IMAGE_FOLDER + '/'+ filename + ' 1\n')
fr.close()
```

But after running following 5th cell(of code):

```
#Importing data
X_train, Y_train = image_preloader(TRAIN_DATA, image_shape=(56,56),mode='file', categorical_labels=True,normalize=True)
```

I have got an error as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-f3e21e2c3936> in <module>()
      1 #Importing data
----> 2 X_train, Y_train = image_preloader(TRAIN_DATA, image_shape=(56,56),mode='file', categorical_labels=True,normalize=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn-0.3.2-py3.6.egg\tflearn\data_utils.py in image_preloader(target_path, image_shape, mode, normalize, grayscale, categorical_labels, files_extension, filter_channel)
    537                             continue
    538                     images.append(l[0])
--> 539                     labels.append(int(l[1]))
    540 
    541     n_classes = np.max(labels) + 1

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sarfaraz/Anaconda3/Dataset_for_Cats_Dogs/train/cat.103.jpg'
```

**Now my questions are:**

> Have there any Hardware/Software issue ? or the problem is in the code
>   ?  If error based on Code then how **Vikramnk** successfully run these
>   codes (record from github) ?

**Some Conditions:**

> All .txt files (as data set) have successfully created. My Machine: HP 245 g5 laptop
>   with 4GB RAM

Hope I've explained my problem as good as possible. I believe at least one person will concentrate on my problem from "STACKOVERFLOW" because near to me **Stackoverflow** is only one source where i can solve my problem of coding within little time.
THANK YOU for your patience!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when the conversion of String to int is not possible. 
In this particular case, the file you are converting "training_data.txt" has some symbols which cannot be converted to int. Typical cases are a space or some other symbols. I believe Your problem is the "_" in your folder name. If not, try finding any other spaces or unexpeted symbols in the file.

For example:

**`/Users/Awal/Desktop/Rakib/CNN/cats And Dogs/train/cat.1236.jpg 0`**

This will trigger an arror because the program finds the first space and takes the next integer and converts it to int. In this case "0"

Solution:

**`/Users/Awal/Desktop/Rakib/CNN/cats And Dogs/train/cat.1236.jpg 0`**

---

Try changing the Folder name "Dataset_for_Cats_Dogs" To a simple string like "DatastForCatsDogs".